# Shipping Address variable (line 1)

Tags: email-templates, shipping-address, variables

am trying to insert a variable (?) into an email template that only includes Shipping Line 1, so the text will say something like:

Your order has been shipped to 123 Smith Street

which is sufficient, rather than including the street, town, zip and country.

Can someone please offer any advice?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can change structure template here:

[image]
And you can change email template here:

[image]

Comment: @Nick_F - my answer helped you?